# Reactstrap button link to section on same page

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to link a button imported from reactstrap to a specific section on my page. I tried many different solutions but none of them seem to work.
Here's how it looks now:

```
2.  import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardTitle, Row, Col, CardImg, CardText } from 'reactstrap';
...
...
23. <Button href="#jump">Thrift shops</Button>
...
...
69. <h5 id="jump">Near city center</h5>
```

So I'm trying to jump to the line 69 from the button used on line 23. I'm lost...

Answer (score 3):

`Button` does not support `href` attribute. You need to use `<a>` tag for that i.e

```
<a href="#jump">Thrift shops</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import Bootstrap CSS in the `src/index.js` file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```